# Echo specific rows on different places

Tags: php, mysql

I want to echo some rows from a mysql-table. My table is called `vm_kuponer`:

```
|id  |uid  |bet  |
|1   |20   |1    |
|2   |20   |2    |
|1   |21   |X    |
|2   |21   |1    |
```

My php is this:

```
$results = $sql->execute();
foreach ($results as $row)
echo ....
```

and here my problem comes. Because, how do I choose the rows with uid = 20 this time, and uid = 21 next time? If I just use `echo $row->bet` it echoes all bets.

What I want is to echo something like this:

```
Name: Brian
Bets: 1, 2
_____________
Name: Dave
Bets: X, 1
```

The design is no problem. But how do I choose the rows with uid = 20 one place and uid = 21 another place? Sorry if it's a stupid question. I have searched, but I can't find a solution :/

Comment: I would suggest you change the query to only select the rows you want to show. But you dont show the query

Comment: Well, I wants to show every row, but I want to decide where the row should be shown? Does that make sence? :)

Comment: Then the answer given is a reasonable start point

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
foreach($results as $result)
{
  if($result->uid==20)
  {
     echo $result->bet;
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code could solve the problem, it is best to add elaboration and explain how it works for people who might not understand this piece of code.

Comment: I think I understand. I just hoped for an easier solution, as I have 10-20 different uid's. But this can work :) Thank you.